# Order Collection View Cells based on customObject Property - Swift 4 -Xcode 9

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I am currently using AlamofireImage to download my images from firebase. The images go into a collection view and the order of the image is important. I have made it so each photo has a tag.

Here is the class for my photos:

```
class businessPhoto {

var image = UIImage()
var url = String()
var tag = Int()

}
```

**I am aware that Alamofire is asynchronous.** I am having trouble sorting my array after the download is complete.

*(Something to do with the download actually being completed vs. the for loop being complete)*

Here is what I am getting:

[image]

This is what I need:

[image]

My Code:

```
    // Creates an Array of URLS
func createURLArray() {

    if selectedBusiness.image1URL?.isEmpty == false {

        imageURLS.append(selectedBusiness.image1URL!)

    } else {

        let placeholder = "--"
        imageURLS.append(placeholder)

    }

    if selectedBusiness.image2URL?.isEmpty == false {

        imageURLS.append(selectedBusiness.image2URL!)

    } else {

        let placeholder = "--"
        imageURLS.append(placeholder)

    }

    if selectedBusiness.image3URL?.isEmpty == false {

        imageURLS.append(selectedBusiness.image3URL!)

    } else {

        let placeholder = "--"
        imageURLS.append(placeholder)

    }

    if selectedBusiness.image4URL?.isEmpty == false {

        imageURLS.append(selectedBusiness.image4URL!)

    } else {

        let placeholder = "--"
        imageURLS.append(placeholder)

    }

    if selectedBusiness.image5URL?.isEmpty == false {

        imageURLS.append(selectedBusiness.image5URL!)

    } else {

        let placeholder = "--"
        imageURLS.append(placeholder)

    }

    if selectedBusiness.image6URL?.isEmpty == false {

        imageURLS.append(selectedBusiness.image6URL!)

    } else {

        let placeholder = "--"
        imageURLS.append(placeholder)

    }

    if selectedBusiness.image7URL?.isEmpty == false {

        imageURLS.append(selectedBusiness.image7URL!)

    } else {

        let placeholder = "--"
        imageURLS.append(placeholder)

    }
    downloadImages(URLArray: imageURLS)

}





// ** Image Download
func downloadImages(URLArray: [String]) {

    for stringURL in URLArray {

        // Temporary Object 
        let object = businessPhoto()

        //Sets tag for object
        if stringURL == imageURLS[0] {

            object.tag = 1

        } else if stringURL == imageURLS[1] {

            object.tag = 2

        } else if stringURL == imageURLS[2] {

            object.tag = 3

        } else if stringURL == imageURLS[3] {

            object.tag = 4

        } else if stringURL == imageURLS[4] {

            object.tag = 5

        } else if stringURL == imageURLS[5] {

            object.tag = 6

        } else if stringURL == imageURLS[6] {

            object.tag = 7
        }

        if stringURL == "--" {


        } else {

            // Downloads Image 
            let url = URL(string: stringURL)
            Alamofire.request(url!).responseImage { response in


                if let image = response.result.value {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        object.image = image
                        object.url = stringURL
                        self.currentImages.append(object)
                        self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
                    }


                } else {


                    object.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image-failed")
                    object.url = "--"
                    self.currentImages.append(object)
                    //self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        }


    }
    //completion()
}

//This function should update the collection view to show the photos sorted by their tag but does nothing
 func updateCollectionView() {

    print("UPDATING COLLECTION VIEW")
    print(currentImages)
    currentImages.sort(by: { $0.tag > $1.tag })
    self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, to make it have a right order. Follow my step.

- Create `self.currentImages` with 7 empty `UIImage` at start of method `downloadImages` if it doesn't exist.
- Use `self.currentImages.insert(object, atIndex:object.tag)` instead of `self.currentImages.append(object)`.

  ```
  Alamofire.request(url!).responseImage { response in


      if let image = response.result.value {

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              object.image = image
              object.url = stringURL
              self.currentImages.insert(object, atIndex:object.tag)
              self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
          }


      } else {


          object.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image-failed")
              object.url = "--"
              self.currentImages.insert(object, atIndex:object.tag)
              //self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**EDIT**

```
func checkAndAddUrl(url : String) {
  if url?.isEmpty == false {
    imageURLS.append(url!)
  } else {
    let placeholder = "--"
    imageURLS.append(placeholder)
  }
}

func createURLArray() {

  checkAndAddUrl(selectedBusiness.image1URL)
  checkAndAddUrl(selectedBusiness.image2URL)
  checkAndAddUrl(selectedBusiness.image3URL)
  checkAndAddUrl(selectedBusiness.image4URL)
  checkAndAddUrl(selectedBusiness.image5URL)
  checkAndAddUrl(selectedBusiness.image6URL)
  checkAndAddUrl(selectedBusiness.image7URL)

  downloadImages(URLArray: imageURLS)

}





// ** Image Download
func downloadImages(URLArray: [String]) {

  for stringURL in URLArray {

    // Temporary Object
    let object = businessPhoto()

    object.tag = URLArray.indexOf(stringURL)

    if stringURL == "--" {


    } else {

      // Downloads Image
      let url = URL(string: stringURL)
      Alamofire.request(url!).responseImage { response in


        if let image = response.result.value {

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            object.image = image
            object.url = stringURL
            self.currentImages.append(object)
            self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
          }


        } else {


          object.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image-failed")
          object.url = "--"
          self.currentImages.append(object)
          //self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
      }

    }


  }
  //completion()
}

//This function should update the collection view to show the photos sorted by their tag but does nothing
func updateCollectionView() {

  print("UPDATING COLLECTION VIEW")
  print(currentImages)
  currentImages.sort(by: { $0.tag > $1.tag })
  self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()


}
```

Comment: Ahh yeah, that makes sense. I will try this. If it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: If you can't make it work, let me know. I will show you why your code doesn't work ;)

Comment: @ethanfox27 once more, you don't need to use `if` to check and set `tag` for `object`. Let get index of `stringURL` in `URLArray` and set it for `object`'s `tag`. It's sorter and clearer

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it? If so I'd love to know. I know my method is really repetitive.

Comment: @ethanfox27 i have updated my answer. You can check it again with **EDIT**. Hope it can help you make your code better.

Comment: @ethanfox27 i'm not sure about it will run with any error because i'm not good at Swift. But this is the idea, if having any error, you just need fix it and try

Comment: Just got it to work! I will also make the changes you included as well. It's a lot cleaner. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ethanfox27 i'm not clear about `Just got it to work!`. Did you fix you issue?

Comment: Congratulation @ethanfox27 ;)